# String is not being recognized in visual studio 2013?

Tags: c

I am using c language
I have included the relevant header files

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()

{
    string s = "abcd";
}
```

Comment: There's no type *string* in C.

Comment: use `.cpp` extension. in c no data type `string`

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2013 supports C++. Headers files with a `.h` extensions are C style headers. In C++ prefix `c` before header files and remove the `.h`. Also `main` should return an `int` as per C/C++ ISO Standard.

Also, there is no `string` datatype in `C`. Try this:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
int main()    
{
    const char *s = "abcd";
    return 0;
}
```

And make you save your code file with a `.cpp` extension.

Comment: What is #include <string.h> used for in c then?

Comment: `<string.h>` contains functions that operate on C strings, i.e. null-terminated arrays of chars. It does not define a `string` type.

Comment: if you are using `strcpy()` or `strstr()` or any other functions related to strings then you can include `#include <string.h>`